# Joining 3 tables - If row doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to join tables

- messages_between
- users
- status

I have this SQL:
     `SELECT messages_between.*, users.*, status.* FROM messages_between
       LEFT JOIN users
        ON users.uid = messages_between.user_2
       LEFT JOIN status
        ON status.uid = messages_between.user_2 
       WHERE messages_between.user_1 = 123`

So this query works fine but the problem is when I don't have a row in `messages_between`.
The `uid` is code which is used in columns `user_1` or `user_2`

Any suggestions?
Thanks

**[EDIT]**

My structures of tables:
**users** has columns: id, name, password, password_s, uid
**status** has columns: id, uid, status[if he/she is online or offline]
**messages_between** has columns: id, user_1, user_2, mid

So I want to show users.name, status.status, messages_between.user_2, messages_between.mid

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  If you don't have a row in `messages_between`, what do you want to output?

Comment: Clarify your question what you want to achieve?

Comment: Sorry, when I don't have a row in `messages_between` I want show `null`

Comment: Try rewriting your query to have the table you want all the records from after FROM, then outer join the remaining two tables.

Comment: how can both users uid and status uid point to same column in messages_between table?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query. When you need null from the joined tables then you should not add the conditiona in where clause. Either you also check with null or add the conditiona in join clause.
Also you need to change the order of left join, becuase you want to retrive all the recrods from the users table and null values for the missing messages_between records and status records.

```
       SELECT messages_between.*, users.*, status.* FROM messages_between
       LEFT JOIN users
        ON users.uid = messages_between.user_2 AND messages_between.user_1 = 123
       LEFT JOIN status
        ON status.uid = messages_between.user_2
```

Comment: I have edited the query, basically start with messages_between and then users and status. can you check if this works?

Comment: not exactly, the where condition is moved to join clause

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT messages_between.*, users.*, status.*
FROM users LEFT JOIN
     messages_between
     ON users.uid = messages_between.user_2 and messages_between.user_1 = 123 LEFT JOIN
     status
     ON status.uid = users.uid;
```

This keeps all users, providing additional information when there is an appropriate "message between".

Comment: No, it returned all users and I want to show users which they are in messages_between.user_2